# CORS AJAX request error with Venmo's API

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make a request from my client side code to grab user information from Venmo's API:

```
getUser: function(code) {
    var url = 'https://api.venmo.com/v1/users/:user_id?access_token=' + code;
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      crossDomain: true,
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data)
      },
      error: function() {
        console.log('error');
      },
    })
  }
```

However, when `getUser` is called, I'm getting a CORS error saying:

[image: Access-Control-Allow-Origin Error]

I tried adding the `crossDomain:true` property to the options passed into my AJAX request but that seems to not have any effect. Am I supposed to set CORS headers on the client side somehow?

Comment: Looks as though your client origin is getting to the web service as "http://localhost:5000" but the service is expecting the origin to be coming from https://venmo.com. You can either change what the client origin is, or allow origin of "http://localhost:5000", during development you could allow origin of *

Comment: Try adding header in the requested file (response):                                header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

Comment: To be clear, the above two comments are recommending to change settings on the api.venmo.com server.

Comment: @KevinB exactly; that is the issue because I don't have access to venmo's API server.

Comment: There is no other way around the issue, other than not using the browser to access the api.

Comment: Also, the `crossDomain` property isn't meant for this purpose. It's for forcing a same-domain request to be handled as if it were cross-origin. ***MANY*** people misuse it.